# My Instagram code won't run or open in VS Code

Tags: python

```
from instabot import bot

my_instagram bot= instagram Bot()
#login
my_instagram bot.login(username="", password="")

#follow a user
my_instagram bot.follow("python_app_projects")


#follow multiple users
my_instagram bot.follow_users(["coding_for_beginners_", "python.app", "py_beginners"])


#unfollow the non followers
my_instagram bot.unfollow_non_followers()
```

I'm having issues with my Python Instagram bot. I can't enter my account using my email and password, and I can't mass follow and mass unfollow anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incorrect Code**

```
    from instabot import bot

my_instagram bot= instagram Bot()
#login
my_instagram bot.login(username="", password="")

#follow a user
my_instagram bot.follow("python_app_projects")


#follow multiple users
my_instagram bot.follow_users(["coding_for_beginners_", "python.app", "py_beginners"])


#unfollow the non followers
my_instagram bot.unfollow_non_followers()
```

**Problems**
Problem1- Your Import Statement was incorrect inplace of bot there should be Bot
Problem2-Object Name for class Bot your named it as my_instagram bot you forgot to add _ between instagram and bot.
problem3-When You are creating object for class Bot you named it as `instagram Bot()` but there is only Bot

**Corrected Code**

```
from instabot import Bot

my_instagram_bot=Bot()
#login
my_instagram_bot.login(username="kushaal_mahajan", password="Lovekushp@1")

#follow a user
my_instagram_bot.follow("python_app_projects")


#follow multiple users
my_instagram_bot.follow_users(["coding_for_beginners_", "python.app", "py_beginners"])


#unfollow the non followers
my_instagram_bot.unfollow_non_followers()
```

Comment: I will go vote your answer you was very helpful. Before you go after running the code I'm receiving a exit code 1 error from the traceback  File "C:\Users\MONEY GETTAZ ENT\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from instabot import Bot

Comment: Sir I am working on it

Comment: Till then please vote for my answer

Comment: Then I will post it's answer too

Comment: Okay  I will vote now

Comment: I think you are getting error because you have made a file with same name as instabot
So their names are collapsing
If it is let full let me know

Comment: That’s what I did let me jump on my computer real fast to change the file

Comment: @TechNewbie01 I'm receiving the same error message

Comment: @TechNewbie01 after changing the file name from instabot to main.py I'm still receiving error code 1

Comment: I don't have no documents name instabot  on my computer anymore

Comment: How can I get the code not to read exit code 1?